# Getting the most recent linked entity in a different entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sorry for the confusing title, if anyone knows a better summary please edit.

I have a `Premise` and a `Person`. A person can own a premise, which is then called a `Property`.
This is what my entities look like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Premise
{
    public int PremiseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public virtual Premise Premise { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Owner { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

So now I can easily get the properties a person has / had.

But can I get the `CurrentOwner` from a `Premise` as well?
The current owner would be the `Person` of the most recent `Property`.

I'd think it'd go something like this:

```
public class Premise
{
    public int PremiseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Person CurrentOwner
    {
        get
        {
            return Properties.Where(p => p.FromDate => today && p.ToDate <= today).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

But that won't work because I don't have a `Properties` list near.

Comment: Why don't add `public virtual List<Property> Properties { get; set; }` into `Premise` class?

Comment: @Dennis Because a premise can only be 1 property, being the most recent one.

Comment: But your model describes many-to-many association between `Premise` and `Person` (it doesn't matter, is `Premise.Properties` exists or not). Don't you need to refactor your model?

Comment: @Dennis Indeed you are correct. How would I rewrite my model then to allow a person to own multiple properties, but a premise can have only 1 active owner?

Comment: @Dennis Couldn't that issue be solved by adding a new property to my premise, called `CurrentProperty`, which then links it to the most recent `Property`? The issue still remains then, to be able to select the most recent `Property` for that premise.

Comment: I don't think, that it could be achieved only with re-designing of classes, since the logic of getting current owner must consider current date. It seems, that it is better to query current owner against context, and leave the model as it stated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68147/discussion-between-benjamin-diele-and-dennis).